# Declaring multiple implementations of single function using concepts

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I want to be able to define method implementations for types using Concepts (C++20).

`Value` struct declared in `value.hpp`

```
template <typename T> struct Value
{
    T value;
    Value(T val) : value(val){};
    // For example I'll use `operator bool()`
    constexpr operator bool() const;
    // T can literally be anything, and it still must be conversible to bool/int/etc
}
```

And `bool` operator overloadings are defined in `value.cpp`

```
template<Concepts::is_pointer T> constexpr Value<T>::operator bool() const { return true; };
template<Concepts::has_bool T> constexpr Value<T>::operator bool() const { return (bool)value; };
template<typename T> constexpr Value<T>::operator bool() const { return std::numeric_limits<bool>::quiet_NaN(); };
```

But code above is producting following compilation errors for every definition:

```
src/value.cpp:9:43: error: redefinition of 'constexpr Value<T>::operator bool() const'
9 |  template<Concepts::has_bool T> constexpr Value<T>::operator bool() const { return (bool)get(); };
  |                                           ^~~~~~~~
```

Is there a clean way to achieve desired behavior?

What I tried:

- Definition of a single function (but it can't be overridden)
- Using the `requires` keyword (same error, more verbose)

Comment: OT: `std::numeric_limits<bool>::quiet_NaN()` is meaningless and [always returns 0](http://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.special#:~:text=quiet_NaN()%20noexcept%20{%20return%200;%20}).

Comment: @cpplearner That was a template code (same with int, float, etc), but in this case - yeah, that's meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly define multiple **overloads** of function templates, or member functions of a class template, with constraints, but they must be just that—overloads.  You can’t just declare one member function and then provide it several **implementations**.  So declare them all in`Value`—including the implementations, for simplicity and because these things must go in header files (or module interface units) for the usual reasons.